How do i write the function tjCompress2 from the dynamic library libturbojpeg in qb64 so i can compress a 32 or 24 bits image into a jpeg in a buffer?
I want to use libturbojpeg to make jpegs in qb64 and i don't know how to write the functions. Can someone help me?
Declare Dynamic Library "libturbojpeg"
    Function tjInitCompress ()
    Function tjCompress2 (handle As...


The maine problem i think is with the buffers. I don't know how to make them. I tried with strings and the jpg buffer gets empty.
